# How to summarise data conditional on another variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to summarise data by calculating the mean of values in one column conditional on the values in another column. Here's an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                  xy = c(1:4, 1:4),
                  val = 1:8)
> dat
  group xy val
1     A  1   1
2     A  2   2
3     A  3   3
4     A  4   4
5     B  1   5
6     B  2   6
7     B  3   7
8     B  4   8
```

The desired output is:

```
  group     var val
1     A mean1_2 1.5
2     A mean3_4 3.5
3     B mean1_2 5.5
4     B mean3_4 7.5
```

I thought about combining `summarise` and `case_when` in dplyr but that does not work (or I've not used it correctly).

```
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mean1_2 = case_when(xy %in% 1:2 ~ mean(val)),
            mean3_4 = case_when(xy %in% 3:4 ~ mean(val)))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group mean1_2 mean3_4
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A         2.5    NA  
2 A         2.5    NA  
3 A        NA       2.5
4 A        NA       2.5
5 B         6.5    NA  
6 B         6.5    NA  
7 B        NA       6.5
8 B        NA       6.5
```

Is there another way? I'd like to avoid spreading the data to wide format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your condition but you may try

```
dat %>%
  mutate(key = ceiling(xy/2)) %>%
  group_by(group, key) %>%
  summarise(var = paste0(xy, collapse = "_"),
            val = mean(val)) %>%
  mutate(var = paste0('mean',var)) %>%
  select(-key)

  group var       val
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 A     mean1_2   1.5
2 A     mean3_4   3.5
3 B     mean1_2   5.5
4 B     mean3_4   7.5
```